# Whisker menu remove keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

Using Linux mint 16, with XFCE as desktop environment. I have a problem removing the default keyboard shortcut (Super_L), for opening the Whisker menu.

The shortcut shows up in Application shortcuts, in the keyboard settings.Though, as shown in the image below, I am not able to remove it by clicking remove - nothing happens.

[image: shortcut]

I have also tried modifying ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml to no avail. I can not seem to find an entry for the xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin.

Even uninstalling the Whisker menu does not work.

So my question is, how do I stop the Whisker menu from hijacking my Windows/Super_L key? I want to bind this key to another application launcher.

Comment: Have you tried `reset to defaults`? Of course you'd need then to recreate the other shortcuts.

Comment: `Reset to defaults` seems to clear the shortcuts at first. Though after reopening the keyboard settings, everything is back, including the Super_L shortcut.

Comment: A shot in the dark: Have you tried logging-in/-out? And a `Reset to defaults` in between?

Comment: I am very curious about the theme you are using here. By the way, updating `/usr/share/mint-configuration-xfce/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`, as per @Stepan's answer works. Thank you.

Comment: @Manbroski that would be the [Uncomplicated](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Uncomplicated?content=157986) theme.

Comment: Things seem okay on Linux mint 17.2 XFCE edition. There, I found that the Super_L shortcut does appear in the keyboard shortcut list, can be removed and has the intended effect, permanently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to edit as a root /usr/share/mint-configuration-xfce/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml and comment out or delete this tag:

`<property name="Super_L" type="string" value="xfce4-popup-whiskermenu"/>`

Then logout and login.

Comment: I also had to delete the Super_L line in /home/USER/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml to get this solution to work.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem in Linux Mint 17 XFCE, and the only solution I've found so far was to:

- Uninstall xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
- Log out
- Reinstall xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin <-- this step is vital!

The entry with Super L will still show up in the Application shortcut window, but it is actually disabled.

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was not needed on Linux mint 17.2 XFCE edition. There, I found that the Super_L shortcut does appear in the keyboard shortcut list, can be removed and has the intended effect, permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Actually I couldn't even change my shortcuts from the Window Manager -> Keyboard. The settings didn't save after I close the Window Manager. My solution was to remove (or just move) the Linux Mint's shortcut settings:

```
mv /usr/share/mint-configuration-xfce/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml{,.BAK}
```

and work with only the default XFCE keyboard shortcut configurations:

```
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
/home/user/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

Note: You must log out in order changes to take effect.